# How to display a iframe when click on a link

Tags: javascript, html

I am not a programmer/developer, but held up to modify a piece of a website.

Say, i have a website, where we have 10 links, upon clicking on 1st link, a frame should be displayed with a associated video and with Close button. User can watch that video and can close that frame.(I also wanted to pass the youtube URL as parameter to the below function)

How can i do that?

I tried below html

```
<html>
<body>
<script>
function playme() 
{
    document.getElementByID('video1').style.visibility=true;
    document.getElementByID('video1').src="https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=G2KlPOYu6U8";
}
</script>
<a href="#" id="playvideo" onclick="playme()">Video 1</a></li>
<iframe id="video1" width="520" height="360"  frameborder="0" hidden=true></iframe>
```

But here the iframe is not coming up. How to do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Something like this will work.

```js
/************************************************
 **Call playMe() with the video code and the   **
 **iframe id in the brackets                   **
 ************************************************
 ************************************************
 **https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=xLRM0tQmmC8 **
 **the code after v= so xLRM0tQmmC8            **
 **in this case                                **
 ************************************************/
playMe = function (vidCode, id) {
    var iframe = document.querySelector('#'+id);
    iframe.style.display = "block";
    iframe.src = "http://www.youtube.com/embed/" + vidCode;
};
```

```html
<a href="#" id="playvideo" onclick="playMe('G2KlPOYu6U8','video1')">Video 1</a>

<iframe id="video1" width="520" height="360" frameborder="0" style="display:none;"></iframe>
```

Comment: Though it matches my expectation, the video is not shown or played here. Can you set any youtube url here?

Comment: just edit iframe.src, though honestly I wouldn't use an iframe at all

Comment: tried below: but not working.     function playme() 
{
 var iframe = document.querySelector('#video1');
    iframe.style.display = "block";
    iframe.src = "https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=G2KlPOYu6U8";
}

Comment: Where are you trying it? Someplaces stop you from being able to use external addresses in iframes, also the url should be http://youtube.com/whatever

Comment: Here it is working @Uday http://jsfiddle.net/link2twenty/4eLq6td6/ I've changed it to make it a bit easier to use.

Comment: That works perfect. Can you just help me bit more. When i click on a link a frame like window should come and the video should be played in there like, once u just navigate to this URL https://www.udemy.com/mobile-automation-using-appiumselenium-3/, click on preview button, you will get the preview in a window or frame. How can i do that???

Comment: Why the below doesnt display the iframe?  <html>
<head>
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="myCSS.css">
<script>
 function playVideo()
 {
  //document.getElementByClass("videoiFrame").style.visibility="visible";
       document.getElementByClass("videoiFrame").style.display = "block";
 }
</script>
</head>
<body>
<a href="#" onclick="playVideo()">Click Me</a>
<iframe class="videoiFrame" style="display:none;"/>
</body>
</html>    iframe.videoiFrame
{
 width:500px;
 height:400px;
 border-style: solid;
 background-color:yellow;
}

Comment: @Uday why don't you use the code I gave rather than changing it? :-)

Comment: Due some issue in my the code breaks, but your code works fine, so using it.

Answer (score 1):

`style.***` properties expect their values to be **strings** not booleans.

`true` is not a valid value for the `visibility` property, you must use `"visible"` or `"hidden"`.

That won't actually help though because the reason you can't see the iframe is not because it is `visibility: hidden`.

Change `hidden=true` to `style="visibility: hidden;"` as well.

Answer (score 1):

You have to change getElementBy**ID** to getElementBy**Id**

Use **display: none** and **display: '**' to show and hide iframe.

You have to use the embedded iframe's url from youtube to avoid "Load denied by X-Frame-Options" error. https://www.youtube.com/embed/G2KlPOYu6U8

Your code must be:

```
<html>
<body>
<script>
function playme()
{
    document.getElementById('video1').src = "https://www.youtube.com/embed/G2KlPOYu6U8"; //use embed url from you tube
    document.getElementById('video1').style.display = ''; //set display to default
}
</script>
    <a href="#" id="playvideo" onclick="playme()">Video 1</a><br/>
    <iframe id="video1" width="520" height="360"  frameborder="0" style="display: none;" ></iframe> <!-- use style="display: none;" to hide iframe -->
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Wow, this simply works. I need some more help like, when i click on this link actually the below is displayed and the links are moving down. Can i do something like a window a to display and video played in that video. I am not sure of what exact control needs to be placed.

Comment: Just change    
<a href="#" id="playvideo" onclick="playme()">Video 1</a></li>
to
<a href="#" id="playvideo" onclick="playme()">Video 1</a><br/>

Answer (score 0):

Change your iframe to this:

```
<iframe id="video1" width="520" height="360"  frameborder="0" style="visibility: hidden"></iframe>
```

And it works, because your javascript is defined to show with the css `visibility` property.

### Edit

Change this javascript piece too:

```
document.getElementByID('video1').style.visibility = "visible"; // instead of true
```

Comment: not working, as i told i dont want to display that iframe before. I should b getting only on clicking on the link.

Comment: I think that you don't test it. That's exactly what you need. First the frame doesn't show. When the user clicks, the visibility changes to `visible` and the iframe shows. Test it and return.